# KDB+, casting, left operand

Tags: kdb

Just started with KDB+, have some questions which is hard to get from the Q for Mortals.

Say, here
http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/casting_and_enumerations

Cast is also atomic in its left operand.
        `5 6 7h$42`
result:

```
42h
42
42j
```

I can't get what we are doing here: it looks like we cast 5 6 7 to 42, but what is 42? Does it represent a type?

Comment: If you get confused with parsing rules, use the `parse` command like so: `parse"5 6 7h$42"` - you'll see `$` uses the left arg as casters

Answer (score 6):

In this case you are actually casting the number 42 to three types, 5h/short, 6h/int and 7h/long creating a heterogeneous list, type 0h.

More information on types can be found here:
http://code.kx.com/q/ref/datatypes/

The example below should make it clearer.

```
q)5 6 7h$42
42h
42i
42

q)`short`int`long$42
42h
42i
42

q)(5 6 7h$42) ~ (`short`int`long$42)
1b
```

Answer (score 2):

To understand it let's convert it to alternate versions.That will make it more simple to understand.

**Version1: Using Each-Left**

```
(5 6 7h) $\: 42
```

Output:

```
42h
42i
42
```

Each-Left(`\:`) says, for each value of left list  call the casting operation on right.

**Version 2:Using Each (simple  loop)**

```
{x $ 42} each 5 6 7h
```

It is just looping over the list and calling lambda function on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way the casting operator(`$`) is used; casting the strings to other datatypes. The most common example where this form is used is while loading the data from CSV to kdb session.

```
q)"HIJ"$\:string 42
(42h;42;42j)
```

or

```
q)-5 -6 -7h$\:string 42
(42h;42;42j)
```